# A problem with Lebesgue integral in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, distribution-theory, functional-calculus

Let $ F \in D '$ have a compact support, $ F(\varphi)\geq0$ for any $\varphi \geq0$. How can i prove that $F(\varphi) = \int \! \varphi \, \mathrm{d}\mu$  for some non-negative measure $ \mu $?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called 'Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem'.

Comment: Yep, but it has very large proof. I think its easier to prove it because we are in $D'$ (in theorem we are in $C$) and i don't know how

Comment: The proof simplifies not because of $D'$ but because one is on $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of a general Hausdorff locally compact topological space. You typically need continuous approximations of indicator functions of compact subsets $K$, and Uryshon lemma type technicalities. You can instead use things like $d(x,A)/(d(x,A)+d(x,B))$ for closed sets $A$ and $B$, etc. Other than that you basically have to go through the proof of the $RMK$ theorem.

Comment: An idea: For an open set $U,$ set $\mu(U) = \sup \{ F(\varphi) \mid 0 \leq \varphi \leq \chi_U,\ \varphi \in C_c^\infty \}$ with $\mu(\emptyset)=0.$ Can it be shown that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive? If so, $\mu$ is a Borel measure. Can it then be shown that $\int \varphi \, d\mu = F(\varphi)$?

Comment: But from the Uryson lemma we cannot conclude that the function is represented as an integral over a finite measure